# Position text to center of div left and right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create something that looks like this:

[image]

so far I have: http://jsfiddle.net/ePse6/

Without using something like: `margin-top:-25px;`, how can I position the Edit/Delete links to be on the right of the title (the part that says "iPhone" or "Android") and have both the title and links halfway between the borders?

Thanks!

Comment: you should read up on absolute and relative positioning with css.

Comment: I changed it up some, but here's an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ePse6/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just like most of answers, here i come with `text-align:right` and `float:left` .

I reduced code to minimal and plain CSS for your actual structure and to make it clear to you : http://jsfiddle.net/ePse6/7/

```
ul , a { /* basic reset we need */
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    color:gray;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.mini > ul > li {
    display:block;/* reset from list-item */
    border-bottom:solid;
    text-align:right;
    overflow:hidden;/* wraps floatting element within */
}
.mini > ul > li> h3 {
    float:left;
    margin:0;
}
.mini > ul > li  ul,
.mini > ul > li  li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: you can increase height of container via margins on content http://jsfiddle.net/ePse6/8/ or use a line-height http://jsfiddle.net/ePse6/9/

Answer (score 0):

You should create two columns that fill the parent div. Make them both `float:left;` and for the right column you can align the text to the right `text-align:right;` or put two divs in it with `float:right;` for `edit` and `delete`.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ePse6/5/

Whatever you put into the columns or how to format it is up to you. But from here you have 2 columns independently next to each other.

If you want multiples of these stacked on top of each other i would change the container to a class and just add multiple of these containers with the columns to keep it tidy and readable. Like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ePse6/6/

HTML:

```
 <div class='container'>
     <div class='leftCollumn'>
         Iphone
     </div>
     <div class='rightCollumn'>
         <a hreft="">Edit</a><a hreft="">Delete</a>
     </div>
</div>
 <div class='container'>
     <div class='leftCollumn'>
         Iphone
     </div>
     <div class='rightCollumn'>
         <div class="button">Edit</div><div class="button">Delete</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container
{
    width:600px;
    margin:auto;
}
.leftCollumn
{
    float:left;
    width:400px;
    background-color:#999;
}
.rightCollumn
{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    text-align:right;
    background-color:#CCC;
}

.rightCollumn a
{
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:5px;
}

.button
{

    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:5px;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#FFF;
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something simple and really handy?

I have removed all of your messy code, and have created a new fiddle for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/ePse6/4/

I have used just a few lines of code, I have used a div and inside that, I have used 2 paragraphs to seperate each of them. Then inside that I used span element to seperate the right and left floating elements.

Using CSS I selected the classes and then styled them to get the desired input!

Here is the code:

```
<div>
    <p>
       <span class="left">Android</span><span class="right">Delete Edit</span>
    </p>
    <p>
       <span class="left">iPhone</span><span class="right">Delete Edit</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS is as:

```
p {
    border: 1px solid #333; // border that you wanted!
    padding: 20px; // padding all around the element
    padding-bottom: 40px; // padding at the bottom of the element
}

.left {
    float: left; // making the elements float at the left
}

.right {
    float: right; // floating elements at the right side
}
```

You can go to the fiddle page, and check for the design of the layout now. It was a simple thing. Hope its what you wanted.

Comment: The downsides of something like this is you can't control the styling of the Delete and Edit buttons

Answer (score 0):

This is without the lists. Just some CSS to do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/Lg96p/

CSS:

```
.wrap{
width:100%;
border-bottom:solid 1px #666666;
margin-bottom:20px;
padding-bottom:10px;
}

.title{
font:bold 16px arial;   
}

.fl{
float:left;
}

.fr{
float:right;
}

.lnk{
color:#6c6c6c;
display:inline-block;
text-align:right;
margin:0 10px 0 0;
text-decoration:none;
font:normal 14px arial;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap fl">
<div class="title fl">iPhone</div>
<div class="fr"><a class="lnk" href="">Edit</a><a class="lnk" href="">Delete</a></div>
</div>

<div class="wrap fl">
<div class="title fl">Android</div>
<div class="fr"><a class="lnk" href="">Edit</a><a class="lnk" href="">Delete</a></div>
</div>
```